# How to include an object from another model in a generic Django CreateView?

Tags: python, django, django-views, attributes

Ok so I am trying to include the corrosponding Comment in my createAnswer View currently the url of the createAnswer page includes the pk ok the right comment so i need to get the comment by the id in the url.
 My generic CreateView looks like this:

```
class createAnswer(CreateView):
   model = Answer
   fields = ['content']
   def getComment(self, request):
    ???


   comment = getComment()

    def get_success_url(self):
       this_path = self.request.get_full_path()
       path_list = this_path.split('/')
       def get_comment_id(self):
           for i in range(len(path_list)):
               if path_list[i].isdigit():
                   return path_list[i]
       return '/blogcontact/comment/'+ get_comment_id(self)
   def form_valid(self,form):
    this_path = self.request.get_full_path()
    path_list = this_path.split('/')
    def get_comment_id(self):
        for i in range(len(path_list)):
            if path_list[i].isdigit():
                return path_list[i]

    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    form.instance.comment = Comment.objects.get(id=get_comment_id(self))
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

My Urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import createAnswer

urlpatterns = [
   path('contact/comment/<int:pk>/newanswer', createAnswer.as_view(), 
   name='answer-create')
]<br>
```

I would like to save the Comment object in a variable so i Can use it in the html template like this {{comment}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you you are confusing the function views and the Class Based Views (CBV), and you never import a request, it is just a parameter your views receive.

In a function view you do the following:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do some stuff
```

For CBV each method is a function:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView


class MyView(CreateView):
    model = Answer
    fields = ['content']

    def get(self, request):
        # do some stuff

    def post(self, request):
        # do some stuff
```

EDIT: To access the url parameters in class based views use self.kwargs, so you would access the comment pk by doing self.kwargs['pk']. Now you just need to get the comment and add it to the context data:

```
class CreateAnswer(CreateView):
    model = Answer
    fields = ['content']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['comment'] = Comment.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # do some stuff
```

Comment: ok i got that i cant do if request.method == 'GET': do some stuff in a class based view now, but wont def get(): override the entire get method provided by the CreateView Class?

Comment: i tried it and got this error: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' any ideas why?

Comment: I need more context, can you edit your question to add more details on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: well im actually trying to display the corrosponding comment object to the answer im creating in the answer in the createAnswer view i somehow got it to work so the pk of the right comment is in the url of the createAnswer view but i feel like its really hacky but i will edit my question to contain the complete createAnswer view Class and my urls.py

Comment: thanks i actually read the docs again and just overid the get context data method it works